# TAL Condition in Plone to hide HTML if it's a Document (Page)

Tags: plone, template-tal, zpt

I'm trying to modify my  /portal_view_customizations/zope.interface.interface-plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline template with a tal expression, so that the document's author and the modification date do not show if the current portal type is a Document (Page).  I don't mind if it shows for News Items, which are time sensitive, but not the Documents/Pages.

This is my failing Plone TAL expression:

```
<div class="documentByLine"
     id="plone-document-byline"
     i18n:domain="plone"
     tal:condition="view/show and not:python:here.portal_type == 'Document'"> 
...
```

I've also tried:

```
<div class="documentByLine"
     id="plone-document-byline"
     i18n:domain="plone"
     tal:condition="view/show and not:context/portal_type='Document'">
```

but still no luck.  The tracebacks are pretty cryptic and don't relate to the TAL expression.  However, if I get rid of my condition for portal_type, then it works again.  Any thoughts are appreciated.  A manual would be good, but I've looked at the official ones, and they don't mention this.

Comment: Might it have something to do with my 'and' clause?  I see from http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Plone-Users-if-else-statements-in-TAL-td312142.html that my second attempt is very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TAL's underlying TALES, the expression-engine of which TAL makes use of, doesn't support the mixing of expression-types in one expression. It's [syntax](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#tales-overview) allows only one expression-type to be specified (defaults to 'path', if omitted, btw), as no delimiter is provided (like a semicolon for chaining several TAL-statements in one element, e.g.).

But instead of mixing three expression-types you can use one python-expression, try:

`python: view.show and context.portal_type()!='Document'`

**Update:**

If you have customized a Plone's default-template via portal_view_customizations ('TTW'), now [restricted python-methods](http://plone.org/documentation/faq/restricted-python-scripts) cannot be accessed, that' why `view/show` throws an error.

It returns the `allowAnonymousViewAbout`-property of the site-properties, you can also check this condition yourself and your expression looks like:

```
tal:define="name user/getUserName" 
tal:condition="python:test(name!='Anonymous User') and context.portal_type()!='Document';
```

**Quick'n'dirty alternative:**

Do it with CSS:

```
body.userrole-anonymous .documentByLine {display:none}
body:not(.template-document_view) .documentByLine {display:block}
```

This will render the hidden elements, but it's helpful for prototyping and such, or 'quickfixes' (no admin available, etc.).

Comment: thank you, I had gotten this working before I read your answer, but yours is much more compact.  Thank you!`code`<tal:x define="portalType context/portal_type; viewShow view/show">
<div class="documentByLine"
     id="plone-document-byline"
     i18n:domain="plone"
     tal:condition="python:viewShow and not portalType=='Document'">...</tal:x>`code`

Comment: After trying yours, it's erring with the familiar "AttributeError: 'TTWViewletRenderer' object has no attribute '__name__'".  So maybe yours would work if I had it in a view, not TTW?